# Bitcoin Core RPC for transactions of a new address without rescanning

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, json-rpc, rescan, importaddress

I currently use the `importaddress` wallet RPC on Bitcoin Core to rescan the transaction history related to an address, which I then query using `listtransactions`. The address import takes about a hour as it necessitates to rescan the whole block chain.

Is there a faster way to query the historical transactions associated with an address using Bitcoin Core?

Comment: Hey, i've edited your post to make it clearer. It contained two questions though so i only kept the first one. Could you open a new question to ask about the providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fraction of the problem solved for me by using Electrumx server. Electrumx rescan block files and indexed trx history information to the another database. It taken about 3 days. Therefore, I could get trx history and some other blockchain information using RPC call or opening web socket connections to the electrumx server.

Answer (score 3):

You can rescan an address, or a bunch of addresses as defined by a range descriptor, using the `scantxoutset` RPC command. This will give you the current UTxOs paying to this (set of) address(es).

However, to rescan the transaction history you will have to use a watchonly wallet and perform a block chain rescan.

Comment: Actually I need to preprocess block chain addresses and rescan all balanced bitcoin addresses so far such that user does not sense slow rescan process. How do it?